# Why java allows "var" to declare generic variable without specifying type, leading to runtime issue?

Tags: java, generics, types, warnings, var

Hi: this code get compiled:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        var list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("hello world");
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1.01);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
```

But with runtime issue. The `list` local variable is of `ArrayList` but not any `ArrayList<xxx>` generic type. Why java let this kind of code pass compilation?

If I change the 1st line into:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then javac reports a warning of unchecked/unsafe operation, suggest to use `-Xlint:unchecked` and re-compile. Why `var` doesn't trigger any compilation error/warning here?

Thanks!

Comment: What runtime issues are you talking about? What is the problem? The second snippet uses raw types.

Comment: The inferred type is `ArrayList<Object>`. There are no issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usage of `var` and the diamond operator together is legal in Java.  There is no compiler rule that there must be a type to be inferred explicitly.

This runs without a compiler or runtime error, which you'd see by trying to run it yourself.  Even if you add a `Thread` to the list, then we can infer that Java infers `Object` for the generic type of the `ArrayList`.  There are no common classes or common interfaces inferred, because Java won't consider subsequent statements.

You can also try to assign the returned value of a call to `get` to say an `Integer`, but the compiler will complain that it can't be converted to the type of your variable, unless you declare the variable to be `Object` or `var`.

```
Integer one = list.get(1); // Error, can't convert Object to Integer
Object o1 = list.get(1);   // Compiles
var v1 = list.get(1);      // Compiles, inferred type: Object
```